# Cannot call xml in MyBatis

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, mybatis

#### Overview

I am creating a web application with SpringBoot.
I am using mybatis for ORMapper.
I created SQL in xml file, but I can't call it properly.

I think there is a problem with the xml file call, but I could not solve it.

Thank you in advance for your help and wisdom.

#### What I want to achieve

I want to execute SQL statements written in an xml file.

#### directory structure

```
src/main
├── java
│   └── com
│       └── example
│           └── userapi
│               ├── UserApiApplication.java
│               ├── batch
│               │   ├── CsvImportJobInvoker.java
│               │   └── CsvImporter.java
│               ├── config
│               │   ├── MyBatisConfig.java
│               │   └── MyBatisMapperScannerConfig.java
│               ├── constants
│               │   └── ErrorCode.java
│               ├── controller
│               │   ├── BatchController.java
│               │   └── UserController.java
│               ├── entity
│               │   ├── PurchasingInformation.java
│               │   └── User.java
│               ├── mapper
│               ├── repository
│               │   ├── PurchasingInformationMapper.java
│               │   └── UserMapper.java
│               ├── service
│               │   ├── PurchasingInformationService.java
│               │   └── UserService.java
│               └── utility
│                   └── Logger.java
└── resources
    ├── application.properties
    ├── com.example.userapi.repository
    │   └── PurchasingInformationMapper.xml
    ├── static
    └── templates
```

#### Relevant source code

I want to call this xml file
resources/com.example.userapi.repository/PurchasingInformationMapper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.example.userapi.repository.PurchasingInformationMapper">
    <insert id="bulkInsert" parameterType="java.util.List">
        INSERT INTO purchasing_information
        (
            sales_date,
            buyer_id,
            product_name,
            comment
        )
        VALUES
        <foreach collection="entities" item="entity" separator=",">
        (
            #{entity.sales_date},
            #{entity.buyer_id},
            #{entity.product_name},
            #{entity.comment}
        )
        </foreach>
    </insert>
</mapper>
```

Caller of the xml file
java/com/example/userapi/repository/PurchasingInformationMapper.java

```
package com.example.userapi.repository;

import java.util.List;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Insert;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.userapi.entity.PurchasingInformation;

@Mapper
@Component
public interface PurchasingInformationMapper {
    int bulkInsert(@Param("entities")List<PurchasingInformation> entities);
}
```

Reference
java/com/example/userapi/service/PurchasingInformationService.java

```
package com.example.userapi.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.userapi.entity.PurchasingInformation;
import com.example.userapi.repository.PurchasingInformationMapper;

@Service
public class PurchasingInformationService {
    private final PurchasingInformationMapper dao;

    @Autowired
    public PurchasingInformationService(PurchasingInformationMapper dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public int bulkInsert(ArrayList<PurchasingInformation> entities) {
        return dao.bulkInsert(entities);
    }
}
```

Reference
build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.30.1'
    implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.2.2'
    implementation 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.39.3.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.1.5'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Reference
java/com/example/userapi/config/MyBatisMapperScannerConfig.java

```
package com.example.userapi.config;

import org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MyBatisMapperScannerConfig {
    @Bean
    public MapperScannerConfigurer mapperScannerConfigurer() {
        MapperScannerConfigurer mapperScannerConfigurer = new MapperScannerConfigurer();
        mapperScannerConfigurer.setSqlSessionFactoryBeanName("sqlSessionFactory");

        mapperScannerConfigurer.setBasePackage("com.example.userapi.repository");

        return mapperScannerConfigurer;
    }
}
```

Reference
resources/application.properties

```
server.error.include-stacktrace=never
logging.file.name=logs/application.log
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:db/database.sqlite3
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC
mybatis.configuration.map-underscore-to-camel-case=true
mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath:/com/example/userapi/repository/*.xml
```

#### What I tried

##### If I don't use xml (if I write SQL in Mapper file), will SQL be executed -> yes.

Once I changed the following two files as follows and executed the insert statement, it was correctly saved to DB.
java/com/example/userapi/service/PurchasingInformationService.java

```
....
    public int bulkInsert(ArrayList<PurchasingInformation> entities) {
        dao.insertUser("11111111");
        return 1;
    }
...
```

java/com/example/userapi/repository/PurchasingInformationMapper.java

```
...
public interface PurchasingInformationMapper {
    @Insert("INSERT INTO purchasing_information(sales_date) values(#{sales_date})")
    void insertUser(@Param("sales_date") String sales_date);
...
}
```

#### Additional information (FW/tools version, etc.)

Springframework.boot 2.7.5

Comment: The XML mapper must be placed in `src/main/resources/com/example/userapi/repository` (i.e. the directory structure must be the same as the corresponding Java interface).

Comment: It doesn't seem to have any problems, and I'm wondering why it can't resolve ..... I need to check if it is not scanned or not compiled in.

Check if the `resources` directory is marked as a resource folder, or try specifying the xml location in `application.properties`, `mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath:/com/example/userapi/ repository/*.xml`

Comment: @山河以无恙
Thanks for letting me know. However, I changed the application.propaties as you pointed out, but it still didn't work (I added the code above). Is something still missing?

Comment: @ave
Thanks for your comment. I think I have the current directory structure correct, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @katahik Currently the XML file is in a directory with the name `com.example.userapi.repository`, right? That is not correct. Look at the 'directory structure' in the question.

Comment: @ave
It's done! Thank you!I have a "com.example.userapi.repository" and a
I thought "com/example/userapi/repository" was the same. Are they not?

Comment: They are not the same. After compiling the project with `mvn compile`, `PurchasingInformationMapper.xml` and `PurchasingInformationMapper.class` must be in the same place, basically.

Answer (score 0):

SQL was executed by changing directory to src/main/resources/com/example/userapi/repository